# syntax highlighting autocmd is not working in neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, autocmd

I am new to vim and esp. in lua scripting. I want to create an autocmd such that all the jinja files will get yaml syntax highlighting.

```
local a = vim.api
a.nvim_create_autocmd( { "BufNewFile", "BufRead" }, {
pattern = { "*.j2" },
command = [[ lua(syntax = "html")]],
})
```

but this is not working. Could someone point the obvious.

DD.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an Example on how i do Lua Syntaxhighlightning for my own `*.luado` files.
Before i have copied ( as super Q User: root.root ) `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/lua.vim` to `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/luado.vim`.
So i can change it independently from original `lua.vim`.
It is not necessary to change `luado.vim` for the Example below.

`~/.config/nvim/lua/init.lua` required by `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
( At First and off course before: `syntax on` )

```
--[[ Automatic Execution of Lua Oneliner if file extension *.luado
With Lua Syntaxhighlighting ]]
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufEnter"},{
pattern = {"*.luado"},
command = "luado vim.api.nvim_command('setfiletype luado') load(line, 'koys_nvim_auto_luado')()"
})
```

Triggers at "BufEnter" and shows that "BufNewFile", "BufRead" not really needed.
( Every time before it is shown from Buffer ;-) )

Impression
[image: Open a *.luado with Syntaxhighlight]

Now lets change to next Buffer with `:bn` to test3.luado
[image: Changed to next Buffer - Autocommand is executed the line]

And back with `:bp` to test2.luado (Output of `set`)
[image: :luado executing the line in test2.luado by autocommand]
(test2.luado will be shown after ENTER/RETURN)

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` instead of `lua()` seems to help

```
local a = vim.api
a.nvim_create_autocmd( { "BufNewFile", "BufRead" }, {
pattern = { "*.j2" },
command = [[ set syntax=html]],
})
```